# Modify function passed as argument

Tags: scala

I have two functions. One is `masterChecker`, wich takes as argument an Int x and a function p, and return the boolean result p(x). Simple like that.

```
def masterChecker(x: Int, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = p(x)
```

Then I have a second function `childChecker`, which is like an alias to `masterChecker`

```
def childChecker(x: Int, f: Int => Boolean): Boolean = masterChecker(x , f)
```

Is there any way to change `f` in the `masterCheker` call on `childChecker`, in a manner that it would run like `!f` ? (if f return true, than make it false)

Like:

```
// inside childChecker
masterChecker(x, !f)
```

I know that I could do it on the masterChecker call with `!masterChecker(x,f)`, but what I want to know is if it´s possible to change a function behavior passed as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use an anonymous function like so:

```
 def childChecker(x: Int, f: Int => Boolean) = masterCheck(x, !f(_))
```

and there you go!

Even more so, you could do a number of things if you want to "modify" `f` within the function scope of `childChecker`:

```
 def childChecker(x: Int, f: Int => Boolean) ={
   def proxy(x: Int): Boolean ={
     val y: Int = //do things
     f(y) //see? "y" not "x"
   }

   masterCheck(x, proxy)
 }
```

that's part of the fun when you're dealing with plain ol' functions. Granted, this "modification" is more of a decorator pattern but it does adhere to the interface.

Comment: Didn't you mean `def proxy(x: Int)` to be `def proxy(y: Int)` ?

Comment: @Ipiepiora No, I meant "y" in there. That's to emphasize that it's not "x" which was passed in. You could modify the "x," like adding _3_ to it.

Comment: Where do you get the `y` passed to the `f` function then? It only appears for the first time there.

Comment: @Ipiepiora In the `//do things` part. You can do whatever you want to `x` in the function like assigning it to some `y` variable which you then pass to `f`, if you even chose to pass it to `f`.

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I was trying to do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nicer to have the function curried? Just asking.